# Site24x7 website shows down when enabling waf on AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-waf, site24x7

Site 24x7 shows website down when we enable waf on AWS ELB.

Does any one has any idea what will be the cause.

I have tried removing multiple rules from waf and found out below rules which causing the issue. Does anyone have idea about this ruleset.

```
AWS#AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet#GenericRFI_BODY,
AWS#AWSManagedRulesSQLiRuleSet#SQLi_BODY and
AWS#AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet#CrossSiteScripting_BODY.
```

Comment: Check your WAF block sample requests. Probably it is due to user agent. Or bot control.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation below to allow the integration between site24x7 and AWS WAF.

https://www.site24x7.com/help/aws/waf-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `AWSManagedRulesAnonymousIpList` `HostingProviderIPList` rule was blocking traffic from Site24x7 monitors. This rule blocks traffic from IP addresses associated with web hosting and cloud providers.

A simple solution is to set the rule action for `HostingProviderIPList` to `Count`. This effectively stops WAF from enforcing this rule, but leaves all of the other rules in the rule group active.